# paperclip upload a file to S3 from remote_url and token needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, amazon-s3, paperclip, remote-access

I'm writing an importation function from a remote service to our app which uses S3. I connect to an api using OAuth as authentication, so every request I make I need to attach the token in the header.  The attachments must be copied to S3 and the model is using paperclip.

I read the file from the api (say origin) with a GET method which returns a response with the body filled in with the content and the header with filename and other information.

**Q:** Now that I have the body of the file in plain text, how do I store it in S3 (destination) with paperclip?

Alternatively

**Q:** I could upload the file to S3 (destination) using remote URL(as described [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL)), but how do I attach the token to the paperclip request to the (origin) api?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an s3.yml in your config directory... Here's a detailed tutorial in setting up paper clip with rails 3: http://doganberktas.com/2010/09/14/amazon-s3-and-paperclip-rails-3/

Comment: I have them and I can already push to S3, the problem relies in getting the attachment with the oauth token FROM the other api OR upload a file from a string

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a conversion tool to generate either a PDF or an editable document, then upload that to s3... Here's a good PDF gem: http://ruby-pdf.rubyforge.org/pdf-writer/ and even a railscast to help: http://railscasts.com/episodes/78-generating-pdf-documents 
and here's an rtf gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/rtf

Since you have the raw data that should work.

Comment: why would I want to convert the file??? wouldn't it be simpler to save the file I get in the response on my application server and upload that to S3? I could even store it in a virtual disk to make it faster but I believe there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Why do you need to upload the data to s3 then? Why not just store it in the database?

Comment: it's simply a requirement.... this is an exportation so it must follow the previous architecture